# Fetch zone_id of hosted domain on route53 using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53, amazon-elb, terraform-provider-aws

Hi I am creating route53 record with terraform, I already have a hosted domain (public) lets say `example.com` how to fetch its zone_id and attach to record. How can I fetch the zone_id of existing route53 hosted zone. I have written a file but what it does it creates another hosted zone `example.com` rather then fetching existing `example.com`

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  name = "example.com"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.selected.zone_id 
  name    = "dev.${data.aws_route53_zone.selected.name}"
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = var.alb_dns
    zone_id                = var.zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add `private_zone = false` too

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "selected" {
  name         = "test.com."
private_zone = false
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.selected.zone_id 
  name    = "dev.${data.aws_route53_zone.selected.name}"
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = var.alb_dns
    zone_id                = var.zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

Comment: ```

data.aws_route53_zone.non-prod-zone: Refreshing state...

------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:

Terraform will perform the following actions:

Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Means that it can't fetch existing Hosted Zone

Comment: I no longer see a private_zone false attribute in the docs.. Is this undocumented?
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_zone
I am using cdktf to generate the tf code, so I cannot use unspecified vars.

Answer (score 5):

In terraform, data sources can be used to retrieve information at runtime. The AWS provider includes a data source for route53 zones. Here is an example of its usage:

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "selected" {
  name         = "test.com."
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.selected.zone_id 
  name    = "dev.${data.aws_route53_zone.selected.name}"
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = var.alb_dns
    zone_id                = var.zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

Comment: it gives an error `Error: multiple Route53Zone found please use vpc_id option to filter`

Comment: @aws-noob If you have more than one domain with the name "test.com", then you will need to provide additional filters so that only one domain is returned. See the documentation for all the parameters the data source accepts: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/route53_zone

Answer (score 0):

Re-requirements:

- I already have Hosted Zone (region: global at AWS)
- I want to $(teraform output) Hosted Zone Id for further use in configs

Solution:

1. create an empty resource:

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "non-prod-zone" {}
```

2. import recourse

```
terraform import aws_route53_zone.non-prod-zone YOUR_HOSTED_ZONE_ID
```

3. argument your resource with name

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "non-prod-zone" {
  name = var.non_prod_hosted_zone
}
```

4. $(terraform refresh) will output your variable

```
Outputs:

hosted_zone_test_envs_id = YOUR_HOSTED_ZONE_ID
```